# Different login pages for different IPs

Tags: sharepoint-online, authentication, landing-page

I am new to working with SharePoint, as I Co-op student I have been tasked with helping my team move from SharePoint 2013 to 2016. They have wasted quite a bit of time on this issue and have now gotten me to research it for them. I've found quite a bit of information already but I really do not understand many pros and cons etc. Moreover, to present the idea to our lead we require some evidence that somebody somewhere is using the solution.

**The Issue**

In the current SharePoint 2013 if an internal user goes to the site they can login with their network or perhaps AD credentials, while if somebody is accessing it from outside our network/VPN a different login page is displayed where they can use their credentials or login as some sort of guest or temp user. They accomplished this using a Solution called Orbit. Orbit seems to no longer be viable, let alone the fact I can't find any information on it and any links they have are now dead.

This is a functionality they require us to implement.

**Potential Solution?**

The only concrete solution I have come across would be using something like a load balancer. If this is genuinely viable but not the only soltuion, are there pros and cons to using it when compared to other methods?

Our team has a strict budget and getting a load balancer seems fairly distant, though, if the only solution one we could go for.

**Thanks in advance,**

I appreciate any and all help. I am extremely sorry if this question is redundant, I'm learning this terminology and may miss some very obvious things as such. I greatly appreciate the time of each and every individual who reads this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My strong suggestion would be instead of relying on a SharePoint solution, implement a pre-authenticating reverse proxy. Microsoft has two of those available, AD FS + Web Application Proxy or Azure AD App Proxy.

There are many 3rd party proxy offerings, such as F5, KEMP, Cisco, and so on.

Comment: Looking into using AD FS + WAP, it would seem those do require a load balancer, correct? I apologize in  asking you again, most of the examples I've found haven't shown much in terms of what is really going on and I am in need of a very clear cut yes or no.

Comment: If you use a single WAP and single AD FS box, no they don't. Though a non-highly available configuration is never recommended for any service that supports it.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and detailed response! I really appreciate it.